# Mongodb Relationship: Posts and Comments (ref v sub-documents)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but they're too old and since Mongodb has evolved alot for last 5-6 years I am looking for a good schema design.

**Goal:** I want to have a post with comments by users.

What I have designed so far is:

- Separate **post** model:

```
const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    image: { type: String, default: undefined },
    description: { type: String, required: true, minLength: 200, maxlength: 500 },
    comments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'
    }],
    state: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    collaborators: { type: Array, default: [] },
    likes: { type: Array, default: [] }
})
```

- And a separate **comments** model:

```
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    comment: { type: String, required: true },
    project: { type: String, required: true, ref: 'Project' },
    user: { type: String, required: true, ref: 'User' }
})
```

*The reason I am going for the relational approach is because if the comments increase to say 10,000 in number, it will increase the size of schema by alot*.

This way, no matter how many comments we can populate them using their **IDs**, also, we will have different collection for comments iself.

Reference : [one-to-many](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)

Is this a good approach for my project?

---

The way I am querying the comments from one single post:

```
const project = await Project.findById(
        new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.projectId)
    ).populate({
        path: 'comments',
        populate: { path: 'user' }
    }).lean()
```

Answer (score 2):

Whether it's a good design depends how many comments per post do you expect, and what query will be performed on your app.

There's a good blog from [mongodb.com](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) on how to design your database schema

The common design is:

- One to Few (Use embed)
- One to Many (Use embed reference)
- One to squillions (The usual relational database one-to-many approach)

Summary is:

> So, even at this basic level, there is more to think about when designing a MongoDB schema than when designing a comparable relational schema. You need to consider two factors:
>
> - Will the entities on the “N” side of the One-to-N ever need to stand alone?
> - What is the cardinality of the relationship: is it one-to-few; one-to-many; or one-to-squillions?
>
> Based on these factors, you can pick one of the three basic One-to-N schema designs:
>
> - Embed the N side if the cardinality is one-to-few and there is no need to access the embedded object outside the context of the parent object
> - Use an array of references to the N-side objects if the cardinality is one-to-many or if the N-side objects should stand alone for any reasons
> - Use a reference to the One-side in the N-side objects if the cardinality is one-to-squillions

There is also [a blog](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2) about advanced schema design which is worth the read.

---

You seems to be using the [two-way referencing](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2) approach.

The difference between yours and one-to-squillions is you are not only storing post id reference on comment document, but also storing comment ids as reference in post document, while one-to-squillions will only stores project id reference in comment document.

Using your approach will be better if you need to get comment ids of a post. But the disadvantage is you need to run two queries when deleting or creating a comment, one to delete / create comment id from post, and the other one to delete / create the comment document it self. It's also will be slower to find "which post belongs to given comment id".

While using one-to-squillions would gives you worse performance when performing a query to get comments by post id. But you can mitigate this by properly indexing your comment collection.

Comment: Thank you for the brief explanation. Though I am a little confused with what you said in the points regarding one-many vs one-to-squillions. Approach for them sounds similar to me as I read it. Would really appreciate if you could differentiate between their respective approaches.
```Also```, as per this doc, creating a separate model for large numbers looks like a better approach : => https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#embedded-document-pattern

Comment: I read your schema wrong, you seems to be using two-way referencing, not one-to-many. One-to-squillions might be better for your use case, check my edited answer. In short, it depends on what query will be performed on your app.

Comment: Yes, that was intentional.  I updated my answer to show how I am querying comments related to a single project. **Reason** : because if we have 1000000 comments related to 1000 different posts in a comments model, it would have to query 1000000 comments for ONE ```post _id```. Isn't it better to just populate the local array of ```comment_id``` directly from the post itself?

Comment: You are correct, both have advantages and disadvantages, please check my edited answer again. It comes down to which query will be performed to most on your app.